# Powershell ISE breaks when using CMD /C Pause

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-ise

I'm newer to PowerShell, transitioning from batch, so forgive me if I make a stupid mistake. I really like using Powershell ISE. But with the current script I'm trying to run, I use the `cmd /c pause | Out-Nul` command and it breaks ISE by not allowing me to continue any further.

I was trying for a long time to find some way to pause but not show output from the command and I found the `cmd /c pause` command. I can run it fine in a normal PowerShell prompt but ISE just isn't having it.

Anyone have any ideas why this happens or a better alternative to `cmd /c pause Out-Nul`? Thanks and any advice is more than welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Powershell ISE doesn't redirect STDIN (which pause needs).
2. Shelling out to cmd for the pause command is unneeded.

See [this post](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/read-single-key-from-ise/)  for more info on the ISE not being able to take stdin.  You won't find your specific issue but the problem is the EXACT same problem.

On that page, you will also find a better/native way to do "pause" from powershell...
(aka `[System.Console]::ReadKey($false)` )

Comment: `[System.Console]` won't work in the ISE, it has no console.

Comment: Good info, but @zdan is correct: `[System.Console]::ReadKey($false)` doesn't work in the ISE, but `Read-Host 'Press ENTER to exit'` is a reasonable substitute.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.. I guess I was thinking that he would see this when following the link (the link talks about this)..  What I believe should work in the ISE is `If ([console]::KeyAvailable) {If (([System.Console]::ReadKey($false)).`  I was just trying to show a simple way to pull off the "pause" command from PowerShell.